# check/uncheck an input(checkbox) php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the php variable `$optquaninp = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"optid".$o['id']."\" value=\"1\"/>";` 
and I want to set it as checked/unchecked from a script.

Specifically, I want to change its state by clicking on a card. So I applied script below

```
<script>
$('.card-deck-wrapper').on('click', function(event) {
var val = "<?php echo $optid.$o['id'] ?>";
document.getElementByName("optid1").checked =false;

});
</script>
```

It doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.

```
    $('.card-deck-wrapper').on('click', function(event) {
          var val = "<?php echo $optid.$o['id'] ?>";

         // jQuery 1.6+
         // Use the new .prop() method:
            $('input[name='+val+']').prop('checked', true);
             $('input[name='+val+']').prop('checked', false);

         // jQuery 1.5.x and below
         // The .prop() method is not available, so you need to use .attr().
           $('input[name='+val+']').attr('checked', true);
           $('input[name='+val+']').attr('checked', false);

    });
```

Comment: My question has been edited for being more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It did't worked :/.. 
The checkbox works. But with the card attribute no ..